# card-columns is killing links in the second column in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, bootstrap-4

I can't figure out where my problem is. I am trying to use card-columns for the Woocommerce category pages. It formats properly and the first columns links work but the second, third, etc all lose their links. I have been searching but have found no answer, honestly I can't find anyone with the problem

Loop-start.php

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mx-auto">
        <div class="card-columns">
```

Content-product_cat.php

```
<li <?php wc_product_cat_class( 'd-inline-block card', $category ); ?>>
<?php
/**
 * woocommerce_before_subcategory hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_link_open - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory', $category );

/**
 * woocommerce_before_subcategory_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );

/**
 * woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_title - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', $category );

/**
 * woocommerce_after_subcategory_title hook.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', $category );

/**
 * woocommerce_after_subcategory hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_link_close - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', $category ); ?>
```

I did try changing the LI to a DIV and that didn't change anything and I do have 3 close div tags in the loop-end.php. Again the first column works fine, there is some sort of problem when it moves to the second column.

Here is a static example. I have figured out that it is Chrome that is having this problem, it works fine in Firefox and Edge. It is definitely the "card-columns", if I change it to card-deck or card-group the links work fine

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row mx-auto">
    <ul class="card-columns">
        <li class="d-inline-block card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#"><button class="btn btn primary"></button></a>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#"><button class="btn btn primary"></button></a>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#"><button class="btn btn primary"></button></a>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#"><button class="btn btn primary"></button></a>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#"><button class="btn btn primary"></button></a>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#"><button class="btn btn primary"></button></a>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#"><button class="btn btn primary"></button></a>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#"><button class="btn btn primary"></button></a>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#"><button class="btn btn primary"></button></a>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#"><button class="btn btn primary"></button></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Might be easier to debug if you provide a static example.

Comment: I added a static example above

Comment: I have faced the same issue with bootstrap 4 card-column. Links beyond first column cards are not clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Able to fix it by wrapping card inside of another element.

Provided li element with `d-inline-block w-100` classes and used it to wrap the `card`.

```html
<div class="row mx-auto">
      <ul class="card-columns">
        <li class="d-inline-block w-100">
          <div class="card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#">
              <button class="btn btn primary"></button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="d-inline-block w-100">
          <div class="card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#">
              <button class="btn btn primary"></button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block w-100">
          <div class="card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#">
              <button class="btn btn primary"></button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block w-100">
          <div class="card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#">
              <button class="btn btn primary"></button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="d-inline-block w-100">
          <div class="card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#">
              <button class="btn btn primary"></button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block w-100">
          <div class="card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#">
              <button class="btn btn primary"></button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block w-100">
          <div class="card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#">
              <button class="btn btn primary"></button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="d-inline-block w-100">
          <div class="card">
            <h3 class="card-title">Card Stuff</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
            <a href="#">
              <button class="btn btn primary"></button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
```